# Remove some parts of url by htaccess in apache2 server

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, model-view-controller

I'm trying to rewrite url by .htaccess on apache2 server in ubuntu 14.04. I have the following url :

```
localhost/compare/compares/single/16/postoneVSposttwo
```

But I want it like:

```
 localhost/compare/compares/postoneVSposttwo
```

I have tried by following .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)/single/.+/(.+)$ $1/$2 [L,NC,R]
```

But it make a url like:

```
localhost/var/www/html/compare/webroot/compares/postoneVSposttwo
```

How can I solved the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/single/[^/]+/(.+)$ /compare/$1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Hi, great it may work. But still little problem. It creates a url like : http://localhost/compares/postoneVSposttwo  .But i need like: http://localhost/compare/compares/postoneVSposttw

Comment: Hi, now there is an another problem. Its include an extra 'webroot' like follow: localhost/compare/webroot/compares/postoneVSposttow

Comment: Hi, my complete .htaccess rule on this page is as following:     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+?)/single/[^/]+/(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule . /%1/%2 [L,R=302]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [PT,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: check edited answer. Make sure this is just below `RewriteEngine on` line and you test after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: I rarely use skype but you can connect with me on Twitter/LinkedIn (have provided these links in my profile)